# Issue with REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: regex, teradata, regexp-substr

I have text in a column like /AB/25MAR92/ and /AB/25MAR1992/. I am trying to extract just 25MAR92 and 25MAR1992 from the column for a date calculation that I have to work on. Can you please help with the REGEXP_SUBSTR function for this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: the data format format for the day of the month (2 or 02) doesn't matter as I just need the year.2 digits (Mar99) in some cases and 4 digits in some cases (Mar1999)

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

`\b\d{1,2}[A-Z]{3}\d{2,4}\b`

but this will also match `02MAR992`. To exclude this possibility use:

[`\b\d{1,2}[A-Z]{3}(?:\d{2}|\d{4})\b`](https://regex101.com/r/VQrloP/1)

This will match `02MAR1992` and`02MAR92` but will not match`02MAR992`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a pattern like this:

```
\/(\d{2}[A-Z]{3}(19|20)?\d{2})\/
```

- Years are limited to 1900-2099.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AZgtpi/1)

- If you do not want to allow any 2-digit value for the day `\d{2}`,
  you could add this pattern instead `(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` that matches 01-31;

  `\/((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[A-Z]{3}(19|20)?\d{2})\/`
- Or if you allow dates like `/AB/2MAR92/` that have days without a leading zero
  add `(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[1-9])` instead:

  `\/((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[1-9])[A-Z]{3}(19|20)?\d{2})\/`

I've used `/` as anchors. If you don't like that, you can use `\b`.

---

In reaction to your latest comments, my recommended pattern looks like this:

```
\b\d{1,2}[A-Z]{3}(?:19|20)?\d{2}\b
```

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).